# How can I invoke return True or retutrn False from a class function of an external file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, tkinter

Can I call, thanks to `self` or something similar, return True or retutrn False from the function of a class of an external file?

I need this because the main file (Page1) needs to know if a result is True or False in order to perform certain operations. For reasons I didn't explain in the question, I need to use self. I don't need to just use return True or return False. The external_class.py file and the main file are related to each other in two ways

I need something like this. Can you help me? Thank you

**external_cass.py**

```
class example:
    def __init__(self, Page1): 
        ........ (various codes)

    def function(self, Page1):
        if self.x > int(float(Page1.y.get())):
            return self.True #HERE
        else:
            return self.False #HERE
```

Comment: Just `return True` or `return False`.  You only need `self` if you're accessing an attribute of the object it*self*.  `True` and `False` exist independently of your class.

Comment: @Samwise Yes, I am doing it. Exactly. I did not want to dwell on the explanation. How can I use self if I am accessing an attribute of the object itself?

Comment: **You don't need to use `self` here.**  Just `return True` if you want to return `True`.  No need to complicate it.  Maybe the thing you're actually having trouble with is in the code that *calls* `function` (in the "main file"), not `function` itself?

Comment: @Samwise You did not understand. You don't know my complete project. For reasons I didn't explain in the question, I need to use self. I don't need to just use return True or return False. The external_class.py file and the main file are related to each other in two ways. I have to use self for True or False. Can you tell me how can I please? Thank you :)

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to "use self for True or False", so you'll have to explain further.  Without that additional context your question is complete nonsense -- you probably actually need something else entirely but don't have the right words to describe it, so you should explain as much as you can with what you do know.  I'm guessing the actual solution is very simple and doesn't in any way involve "using self".

Comment: @Samwise In the main file I have a condition (if) where if the result is True or False, then it prints certain things. True or False is just that in the external class code I published. If I only have return True or return False, then the (if) condition in the main file fails to print anything

Comment: Share that code, please (add it to your question, don't put it in the comments).  I'm almost positive that you simply aren't calling the function correctly.

Comment: @Samwise In the function I tried to write print ("test") and it prints correctly. The function is then called correctly, otherwise "test" was not printed. So the problem is not that the class or function is badly imported into the main file, but the problem is that the (if) condition does not find the return True or False.

Comment: Please share the code.  You're not calling the function correctly in the context of your `if`.  I'd bet a hundred dollars on it.  Unfortunately, there's no way for me to help you fix the mistake if you won't show me what you did.

Comment: @Samwise Bet accepted hahahah. Give me 10-15 minutes to post the code, because it is very long and I have to try to minimize it as much as possible.

Comment: I think all I need is the line that calls `function()` and the `if` that isn't working (probably the same single line of code -- if they aren't, that might be part of the problem).  Nothing else is really relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Samwise I have updated my code. I also put in some comments to explain to you. Hope you can help me. In case of help of course I vote and accept your answer as a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function, you call `prova()` but don't do anything with the return value:

```
        def Button1_func(): #HERE I CALL CLASS
            k = mediagol.Gol_Mediagol_CF(self) #HERE I CALL CLASS
            k.prova(self) #HERE I CALL CLASS
            # implicitly returns None
```

If you want a function to a return a value, `return` the value.

```
        def Button1_func(): #HERE I CALL CLASS
            k = mediagol.Gol_Mediagol_CF(self) #HERE I CALL CLASS
            return k.prova(self) #HERE I CALL CLASS
```

Assuming that `Button1_func` winds up in the `funclist` that's used by `aaa`, it'll now return `True` or `False` instead of `None` when invoked in your `all(func() ...)` and I expect that'll solve your problem.

Comment: I was about to write you a comment then I saw your kind reply. I still finish writing. In practice, I call the function of the external class through def Button1_func (), in order to obtain the function def aaa (). When the code of the external class was not in an external file, but was simply all written in the same main file ... then everything was working fine and correct. Now I try your code.

Comment: Good. Everything is fine. You won the bet hahah. The solution was also easy. I had been hitting my head for hours and I was no longer clear about finding an answer. Sometimes you should take a break. A thousand thanks

Comment: Could you also help me with this question please? Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71474095/in-a-tabcontrol-how-can-i-apply-icons-and-text-to-the-center-and-margin-of-spac